# Filter row in DataGridView in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, rowheader

I am doing a project where I have to filter row using rowHeader in Header. in DataGridView in vb.net. Can you help me to find the correct way to filter. I can't use.RowFilter. I am using 4.8 .Net framework.

```
 Dim searchText As String = txtSalesReport.Text.Trim()

 If String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) Then
     DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
     Exit Sub
 End If

 For Each row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
     Dim rowHeader As String = row(0).ToString()

     If rowHeader.Equals(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
         Dim filteredTable As New DataTable()

         For Each column As DataColumn In dataTable.Columns
             filteredTable.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType)
         Next

         filteredTable.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray)

         DataGridView1.DataSource = filteredTable

         Exit Sub
     End If
 Next

 DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
```

Comment: *"I can't use.RowFilter"*. Why not? Please provide a FULL and Clear explanation of the problem. You have no idea how many times someone has said that they can't do something but they actually can and they just didn't understand the problem. You need to actually explain your problem and show us what you have done to try to solve it, not just tell us what you want done and wait for us to do it for you.

Comment: By the way, this has got absolutely nothing to do with row headers, based on what you've posted. You're filtering based on the data in the first column.

Comment: As for the code you have posted, how does it make sense to loop through the rows and then, for each row, loop through the columns and add them to another table? If you have more than one matching row then you're going to add the same columns over and over. This is what happens when you write code without first getting a clear understanding of what the code has to do and not bothering to debug the code after writing it. You need to do both before posting a question here. Work out what your code has to do first, then write code to do it. No way you wanted to add columns multiple times.